# Multiple columns for languages vs. serialized array in a one column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table in a more accurate and professional manner.

I need two fields `TITLE` and `DESCRIPTION` for two languages, but I'm not quite sure if I won't add a third language after a while.

Which one would you prefer?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
id | title_en | title_ge | description_en | description_ge
-----------------------------------------------------------
...|..........|..........|................|................
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
---------------------------
id | titles   | descriptions
---------------------------
...|serialized| serialized
---------------------------
```

where serialized is like this

```
array(
 'en' => 'title for english',
 'ge' => 'title for georgian'
)
```

Or any other suggestions? Thanks for future recomendations.

Comment: Do you have any requirements such as being able to search titles or descriptions specific to one language?

Comment: You should probably create another table (eg. language) and change the table you have to: id, title, description, language_id. This way you can add as many languages as you like without changing your tables.

Comment: @VoitekZylinski In this case I will need to add record for each language, and my current case is for video interview files, where adding the same thing is not a good idea. I guess...

Comment: Your query should fall back to the primary language of your website (so you don't duplicate records for each language version when there's no translation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in a combination of two tables.

Your first table should include titles and description in just english. Similar to what you have right now.

Your secondary table will include translations. With a structure something like:

```
-----------------------------------
doc_id | lang | title | description
-----------------------------------
```

You would put a primary key that would include both doc_id and lang and fulltext indexes on title and description.

This way you could construct a query that would fallback to the original english text if a translation for the language you are looking for does not exist, as well as limit your searching to one specific language or another.

Comment: okay, i think i have an idea now, thanks for your time. i'll accept an answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table with four fields
(id,title,description,language)

```
--------------------------------------
id | titles   | descriptions | language
---------------------------------------
 1  |title in en| desc in en | en
----------------------------------------
 2   |title in ge| desc in ge | ge
```

Comment: i think such upproach is good, but there's another column in real case called 'file' so file needs to be duplicate in two rows. i'll still think over it. thanks!